# Select sound card with console commands

Tags: audio, sound-card, cinnamon

Is it possible to use cinnamon-settings app in the command line to change the default sound card? The default sound card does not seem to be set in dconf. 
I'm trying to write a script that switches between HDMI and analog sound output.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for

```
pacmd set-default-sink <sink_name|index>
```

as outlined in
https://askubuntu.com/questions/690711/change-sound-output-from-command-line
and https://askubuntu.com/questions/14077/how-can-i-change-the-default-audio-device-from-command-line

You can get the available index with

```
pacmd list-sinks|grep index|awk '{print $NF}'
```

If you want to control the volume you can do that on the commandline with alsamixer (ncurses) or amixer.

If you are going to play with pulseaudio settings then

```
cp -i /etc/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/
```

will give you your own copy that is safer to edit

```
pulseaudio -k  #should restart pulseaudio after you change settings.
```

For your script you may want to check that the available audio rates are compatible with your sink-device:

```
grep rates $(grep -ci hdmi /proc/asound/card*/codec#0|grep -v :0|sed 's,:.$,,'|head -n1)
```

and depending on which profile each card is attached to

```
pactl --server "unix:/run/user/$(id -u)/pulse/native"  set-card-profile 1 output:analog-stereo
```

and

```
pactl --server "unix:/run/user/$(id -u)/pulse/native"  set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo
```

may help create useful variables. It looks like someone [has already tried to do what you are doing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Automatically_switch_audio_to_HDMI):

But some of their variables are either archlinux specific or out-of-date. (Though their path to triggering your script may be of help.)

Comment: I tried that but it does not work until i logged of or restarted.

Comment: Did you do pulseaudio -k

Comment: Yes. I also tried with the profile `pacmd set-card-profile 2 output:iec958-stereo`

Comment: if **pacmd list-cards | grep output\:hdmi-stere** finds your card does **pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo** make the change happen? https://askubuntu.com/a/541043/155829

Comment: The settings manager shows the change, but audio still comes on the wrong speakers. When I try pacmd move-output it says index does not exist.

Comment: What does **pacmd list-cards | grep -A1 index** say?

Comment: index: 0
 name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>

Comment: ndex: 1
 name: <alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00>

Comment: **pacmd set-default-sink alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._USB_Audio_Device-00**  should switch the output *pacmd list-sinks|grep name:|sed -e 's/.*<//' -e 's/>$//'* is probably a cleaner way to list the sinks

Comment: Just spun up a clean debian8 machine and until I ran **pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo** the hdmi wasn't listed in *pacmd list-cards* - then I checked **cat /sys/class/drm/card*HDMI*/status** and found my cable was loose

Comment: The move sink just won't work. I found a way using the API of my Desktop Environment. This way it is not compatible to other DEs but at least it works for me now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Will do, but I need to clean up the code first :)